# Diagonalization, algebraic and geometric multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $T: \Bbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^4 $ given by $T(x,y,z,w) = (x+y,y+z+w,z+w,z+w)$.

Determine whether T is diagonalizable. If so, determine a basis $\beta$ $\Bbb{R}^3$ formed by eigenvectors of T and determine the matrix $D =$ $\begin{bmatrix} T \end{bmatrix}_\beta$.

**My approach**

$\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{matrix}$

Eigenvalues are: $\lambda_1 = 2$ ; $\lambda_2 = 1$ ; $\lambda_3 = 0$. Eigenvectors are: $\lambda_1 = (2,2,1,1)$; $\lambda_2 = (1,0,0,0)$; $\lambda_3 = (0,0,-1,1)$.

In relation to algebraic multiplicity for  $\lambda_1 = 1;  \lambda_2 = 2; \lambda_3 = 1.$ And in relation to geometric multiplicity for $\lambda_1 = 1;  \lambda_2 = 1; \lambda_3 = 1.$ Since am $\not=$ gm T is not diagonalizable.

Even if it were diagonalizable, would it be possible to write a 4x4 matrix in a base $\mathbb{R}^3$? Or did I not understand this second part well.

Comment: The phrase "If so, determine a basis $\beta$ $\Bbb R^3$ formed..." probably actually said "If so, determine a basis $\beta$ of $\Bbb R^4$ formed..." (otherwise it does not make good sense). The "If so" indicates that one cannot be expected to do so in the diagonalisable case, which as you argued is not the case here.